# AWS Cloudwatch shows wrong RDS size

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a single RDS instance at AWS, which is -- supposedly -- a `db.m1.large` instance. When viewing Cloudwatch metrics for RDS, I see an option to filter by db instance size, and this filter shows only a single filter option for `db.m1.small`. So basically, I appear to have the RDS interface showing me that I have a `db.m1.large`, and the Cloudwatch interface showing that same interface as a `db.m1.small`. Any hints as to what's going on?

Comment: Did you upgrade the instance from small to large at some point in the past?

Comment: Have you asked AWS Support? They're the only ones that are going to be able to resolve this.

Comment: I did contact AWS Support, and the problem was repaired on their side. Thanks much.